# KMPlayer: Context menu items not deleted after uninstall (KMP bug)

Tags: windows-7, context-menu, kmplayer

I have uninstalled KMPlayer but 2 context menu items *(Play with KMP, Enqueue in KMP)* are still visible when I right-click on any folder. How can I remove these remainders?

OS: Win7 x64

Note: I've uninstalled KMP on different machines several times, and I think this is a bug in KMP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used RegAlyzer to find the items containing "KMPlayer" keys, values, and data in the registry. It found 708 entries! I deleted all of them and now the context menu remainders are gone together with the other KMP filth. I don't know how much this solution is reliable, but it worked. If any, I can accept better alternative solutions.

And the lesson I learnt: KMP is a good player unless you uninstall it! It spoils your registry thanks to its superb (!) uninstaller.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) to remove them.

Comment: I've tried both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of ShellExView, but it couldn't find any items related to KMP. There must be some way to delete these remainders using Registry Editor...

Comment: Have you also tried ShellMenuView?

Comment: I couldn't check it with ShellMenuView because I've deleted the registry items of KMP before you proposed ShellMenuView. But it seems useful. Thanks anyway...

Answer (score 2):

[ShellMenuView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_view.html) can solve the problem.

Comment: I recommend using [ShellMenuView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_view.html) and [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) together, since they both find context entries the other might miss.

Answer (score 2):

> There's no way to remove those menu entries for associated files. There should be an option in Preferences or in the setup wizard.
>
> You can remove the items manually with the registry editor in Windows, or by using the attached registry patch.

— [Source and registry patch](http://www.kmplayer.com/forums/showthread.php?t=15779).