# alternatives for zoom player?

Tags: media-player, software-rec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best video player for Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/15522/what-is-the-best-video-player-for-windows)

is there something that is (nearly)customisable like zoom player...
something that is in the same time featured and simple...
i need many things in a player, so simple() are out of the question...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [KMPlayer](http://kmplayer.en.softonic.com/); it can play all video and audio formats known to man, and is also very easy to use.

Comment: KMPlayer is easyily the most configurable video player you can find and furthermore it's free.

Comment: I was a KMPlayer fan till this [problem](http://superuser.com/questions/68167/kmplayer-context-menu-items-not-deleted-after-uninstall-kmp-bug) occurred. Now GOMPlayer is my friend.

Comment: I didn't know about issue. Since I had KMP installed, I decided to do a little experiment and uninstalled it. And, indeed, I noticed some problems: the context menus, files having KMP icons, hundreds of orphan registry entries. Registry cleaning software didn't help much. However, the newest version available - 2.9.3.1428 Final - doesn't have any of these problems.